# Sequelize many to many table in different microservice

Tags: node.js, sequelize.js, microservices

I have two microservices one microservice have his database with the user table, the other microservice have his database with the groups table. There are many `users` and each `user` can belong to many `groups` or no `group` at all and each `group` can contain many `users` or no `users` at all. In the groups database i have make the join table `groups_users` that have two column `userId` and `groupid`.

I know that with Sequelize I have to do something like this in the group microservice:

```
  export default (sequelize, DataTypes) => {
  const Groups = sequelize.define('Groups', {
    uuid: {
      type: Sequelize.UUID,
      defaultValue: uuidv4().replace(/-/g, ""),
      primaryKey: true
    },
    name: Sequelize.STRING
  });
  Groups.associate = (models) => {
    Groups.belongsToMany(models.Users, {
      through: 'groups_users',
      as: 'groups',
      foreignKey: 'userId'
    });
  };
  return Groups;
};
```

But in this line:

```
Groups.belongsToMany(models.Users, {
```

I haven't the models.Users because it's in another microservice, so in this scenario what is the best way handle this?

Answer (score 0):

A good practice when building microservices is that you should always give a microservice its own database. Letting other bounded context access your database is the first step on falling to the Death Star Pitfall pattern (Architectural anti-pattern where microservices get entangled with each other because of high coupling).

To solve your problem, you might want to give your groups microservice a copy/portion of your users data. In this way, both microservice will have persistence layer independence.

A technique that you can use to implement the sharing of data between your bounded contexts (Users and Groups) is message queues. You can send messages on a queue everytime a user record changes on the users' table and a background daemon can listen for changes from this queue and create a copy/portion of the user record that change on the group database.

For more reference:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/microservices-architecture/architect-microservice-container-applications/data-sovereignty-per-microservice

http://www.pogsdotnet.com/2018/08/api-gateway-in-nutshell.html

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but only the id of the user is shared, there isn’t a simple way to do it?

Comment: Hi, this is the cleanest way possible. I don't want to give suggestions that can be considered as dirty

Comment: have you got some reference more practical than theoretical?

Answer (score 0):

I think what you can do for this too is to create an instance method on group models to fetch the user from another microservice. If you would notice associations are also the way of defining instance methods.

You are building an association to fetch users of a group the same you do use instance methods.

```
group.fetchUser() // should return list of user for this group right?


Group.prototype.fetchUser = ()  => {
  write logic to fetch users from other microservice
}
```

The same way You can define logic to fetch all groups a user belongs to.

Although one important topic to point out here is group has many users, not belongsTo here. and user belongTo many groups